# Data Annotations and MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I did MVC 2 two years ago. I am now using MVC 4 and would like to confirm a few things.

1) In MVC 4, we do not need to create a ModelMetadata class to annotate with data annotations for data validation. We may simply annotate the model classes themselves.

In other words, if we are using the EDM generator to generate a model and corresponding classes for us, then we may create a new set of partial classes with the same names and use data annotation attributes on those partial classes themselves.

We do not need to create a new type of model metadata class and decorate *that* class with data annotation/attributes, like here: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

2) For data annotations to work, we need a reference only to System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations and not to Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations.

3) We do not need to instantiate the default model binder in the Application_Start event in the Global.asax file.

Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. As I remember, there's no difference between MVC 2 and MVC 4 when it comes to this. You didn't have to use `MetadataType` in MVC 2, you could have used partial classes for generated models.
2. I'm not able to find any MSDN doc on `Microsoft.Web.Mvc.DataAnnotations`, but for data annotations to work with MVC you'd need `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations` and `System.Web.Mvc` (it contains some additional attributes like `HiddenInputAttribute`).
3. No, you don't, it's instantiated by framework.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, for question 1, you need to use Metadata classes to annotate the properties of of model-first EF classes in the same way as previously with MVC2. When you use code-first EF classes, you can annotate them directly - the annotations will be used for generating the database as well as for scaffolding the Views.